# The website layout changes as I move Google developer tools window upwards

Tags: html, css

I faced the issue with the layout of website being changed by the Google developer tool window which opens when you click F12. So, to be more clear, when I click F12, the window appears but as I move the window upwards the layout gets changed, that is, gallery section reacts to the window and also moves upwards. I do not even know what is causing such problem. I really need your help. Here is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./external/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./external/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 intro__welcome-box">
        <p class="header__welcome-content">Welcome to our kids School!!</p>
        </div>

</div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row flex-container">
                            <h1 class="logo-box">
                                <a href="#">
                        <img class="logo-box__image" src="./images/logo.png" alt="The logo">
                               </a>
                         <span class="logo-box__motto"> Все начинается с детской мечты</span>
                        </h1>
                    <nav class="navigation">
                        <ul class="navigation__list">
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">О Sunnyvale</a></li>
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">Галерея</a></li>
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">Персонал</a></li>
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="showcase">
        <div class="container-fluid p-h-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
<img src="./primary-original.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="showcase-content">
    <h2>Join Our Journey</h2>
    <p>of World Discovery</p>

    <a href="">Find Out More</a>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="gallery">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>
                Добро Пожаловать в галерею Sunnyvale
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content-links m-v-30">
                <a class="anchor light-red" href="">Узнать больше</a>
                <a class="anchor orange" href="">Смотреть Все</a>
            </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="owl-carousel room-carousel owl-theme">
                <img src="./medium-98dcfe.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="./primary-original.jpg" alt="">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

</div>

    </section>


    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./external/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('.room-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>

CSS code

.header {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

.header [class*='intro'] {
  padding: 2rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.intro__welcome-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  background: white;
}

.logo-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}

.logo-box__motto {
  font-size: 16px;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
      -ms-grid-row-align: center;
      align-self: center;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(88, 87, 87, 0.507);
  padding: 0 1rem;
  color: rgba(88, 87, 87, 0.507);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.logo-box__image {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.logo-box__motto {
  width: 30%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.gallery {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

.gallery .content {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.gallery .content h2 {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.m-v-30 {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.content-links {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
}

.anchor {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.anchor:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.anchor.light-red {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.658);
  margin-left: 7rem;
}

.anchor.orange {
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 7rem;
}

.carousel-container {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.p-h-0 {
  padding: 0;
}

.cloud {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(/cloud.png);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.showcase img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.showcase {
  height: 70vh;
  position: relative;
}

.header__tel-number {
  color: #ff7b00;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navigation__list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.navigation__link a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(44, 43, 43, 0.603);
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s, color .5s;
  transition: background .5s, color .5s;
}

.navigation__link a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #ff7b00;
}

.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.navigation {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}

.intro__address-box p {
  text-align: right;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Comment: This shouldn't have anything to do with your page itself, it rather sounds like your dev tools are docked to the bottom of your window. Click the icon with the three dots in the top right corner of the dev tools and change the "Dock side" to "undock into separate window".

Comment: Because you have adjusted the height in `vh`, `vh` means variable height, it means the height will be adjusted automatically whenever the height of the window changes. In this case, your Developer tools might be docked on the bottom, so whenever you change the height of the Developer Tools, the height of the content in your page changes. To prevent this, what you can do is, dock the Developer Tools on the right (easier), or change the CSS having `vh` values (difficult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `.showcase` section has the height set to `70vh`, which is relative to the viewport-height. When you open the Dev Tools, the height of the window gets smaller, thus 70vh becoming less than with the full screen, thus moving the gallery upwards.

Simply remove `height: 70vh;` from `.showcase` to fix the issue.
Code snippet below:

```css
      .header {
        background: #ecf0f1;
      }

      .header [class*='intro'] {
        padding: 2rem;
      }

      p {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .intro__welcome-box {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
      }

      .navbar {
        background: white;
      }

      .logo-box {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            -ms-flex: 1;
                flex: 1;
      }

      .logo-box__motto {
        font-size: 16px;
        -ms-flex-item-align: center;
            -ms-grid-row-align: center;
            align-self: center;
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(88, 87, 87, 0.507);
        padding: 0 1rem;
        color: rgba(88, 87, 87, 0.507);
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

      .logo-box__image {
        padding-right: 1rem;
      }

      .logo-box__motto {
        width: 30%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
      }

      .gallery {
        padding: 5rem 0;
      }

      .gallery .content {
        width: 40%;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .gallery .content h2 {
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

      .m-v-30 {
        margin: 30px 0;
      }

      .content-links {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
            justify-content: space-around;
      }

      .anchor {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        border-radius: 30px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      .anchor:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
      }

      .anchor.light-red {
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.658);
        margin-left: 7rem;
      }

      .anchor.orange {
        background: orange;
        margin-right: 7rem;
      }

      .carousel-container {
        height: 300px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }

      .p-h-0 {
        padding: 0;
      }

      .cloud {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(/cloud.png);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      .showcase img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .showcase {
        /* height: 70vh; */
        position: relative;
      }

      .header__tel-number {
        color: #ff7b00;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
      }

      .navigation__list {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
            -ms-flex-pack: justify;
                justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .navigation__link a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: rgba(44, 43, 43, 0.603);
        font-weight: 600;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s, color .5s;
        transition: background .5s, color .5s;
      }

      .navigation__link a:hover {
        color: white;
        background: #ff7b00;
      }

      .flex-container {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
      }

      .navigation {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            -ms-flex: 1;
                flex: 1;
      }

      .intro__address-box p {
        text-align: right;
      }
      /*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 intro__welcome-box">
        <p class="header__welcome-content">Welcome to our kids School!!</p>
        </div>

</div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row flex-container">
                            <h1 class="logo-box">
                                <a href="#">
                        <img class="logo-box__image" src="./images/logo.png" alt="The logo">
                               </a>
                         <span class="logo-box__motto"> Все начинается с детской мечты</span>
                        </h1>
                    <nav class="navigation">
                        <ul class="navigation__list">
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">О Sunnyvale</a></li>
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">Галерея</a></li>
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">Персонал</a></li>
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
                            <li class="navigation__link"><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="showcase">
        <div class="container-fluid p-h-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
<img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="showcase-content">
    <h2>Join Our Journey</h2>
    <p>of World Discovery</p>

    <a href="">Find Out More</a>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="gallery">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>
                Добро Пожаловать в галерею Sunnyvale
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content-links m-v-30">
                <a class="anchor light-red" href="">Узнать больше</a>
                <a class="anchor orange" href="">Смотреть Все</a>
            </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="owl-carousel room-carousel owl-theme">
                <img src="https://www.newyorkpass.com/images/rebrand/prices_01.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/new-york.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&w=618&h=410&crop=1" alt="">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

</div>

    </section>


    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('.room-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mirzhal - Run the snippet, press `Full page`, open the Dev Tools and toggle the `height` on the `.showcase` element to see the diference.

Comment: thank you for your reply and yes I removed the height of 70vh but I am facing the same issue. But the snippet that you modified works ok. ???

Comment: @mirzhal - maybe it's because you have different images, with a different size. Could you provide some dummy images, maybe using https://dummyimage.com/ , into a code snippet, so that we could replicate the issue?

Comment: yes Andrei after a thorough examination of the code, it turned out that there was a problem with live server not refreshing the page after the removal of height:70vh so you were right. Look Andrei if vh has such issues should I avoid using it and use px. Thank you in advance for your kind help :)

Comment: please Andrei I really need your professional advice, so should I abstain from using vh I just wanted to create showcase area and in some tutorials I saw that vh or did I use vh incorrectly?

Comment: @mirzhal I use `vh` very rarely in CSS. Usually you can do most types of layout without using `vh` or `vw`. Very often percentage are more useful when it comes to fluid design.
Still, if you want to use `vh`, make sure you test well your application, by constantly resizing the window or changing the viewport to make sure nothing has been affected.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome development tool is not an overlay by default, it's width/height is taken off the display screen. Since your design is responsive, it will adapt to the display size (which is browser window minus developer tool).

Solution: in the developer tool's menu, select "Undock into separate window"

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhWz7.png